# Can I prevent Google Chrome from showing the profile icon for the default profile?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8

Other people use my computer often enough that it makes sense for them to have their own Google Chrome profile. But 95% of the time, I am the one using it, and I don't want space taken up by the profile icon. Can I prevent it from showing for the default profile, even when I have multiple profiles?